# Does Google allow developers to use .txt files to store android app data?

Tags: android, database, storage

I need a lot of text for my app. The .txt file is around 2 MB. Does Google allow devs to make apps which pull their data from txt files? If not, then what are the alternatives to store a lot of information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google allows you to make anything you want.  Yes, some apps read in data from text files.  Just place it in your assets directory and it will be bundled into your apk.  You can put any type of file you want in there.

Another alternative would be a SQLite database, which has native support.

Comment: For the OP: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html